# Breadcrumb separator code?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Drupal uses this symbol for breadcrumb seperation:

```
»
```

However, it shows up really messed up when I put that in code. I.e. It shows this question mark thing. What is the correct markup to display this properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RD, you can use `&raquo;` to show » in HTML or you can change it to another symbol.